# Check if AVPlayer is playing already

Tags: ios, avplayer, audio-player

I have a tableview of songs on the ios device and if I select a row, I push to a new view where AVPlayer starts playing the selected song. Now if I go back and select another row, pushing to the view the app will start playing the new song, while continue to play the one that was running already.

EDIT:
I tried using the rate value like this without success, as it will always output "not playing" if i put it in my viewdidload method, even if a song is playing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    appDelegate = (SimpleTableAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
    if (appDelegate.audioPlayer.rate == 0.0f)
    {
        NSLog(@"not playing");
    } else {
    NSLog(@"already playing");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
appDelegate.audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
```

you seem to be alloc'ing and init'ing a new AVPlayer. As such it's not surprising that you get a "not playing" result. Simply leave out that line.

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer has a `rate` property which indicates the speed of playback as a float. `0.0f` indicates stopped. The `play` and `stop` methods just change the `rate` property.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    appDelegate = (SimpleTableAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //Stop potential existing audioPlayer prior to creating new player
    [appDelegate.audioPlayer stop];

    //Create new audio player
    appDelegate.audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I actually tried rate but this does not fire. I will post the code above that I use without success...

Comment: Your audio player will always be stopped during viewDidLoad. You should stop the existing player instance before creating a new one. Updated answer